# How can I put a string containing html text to be displayed in a javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, html

How can I put a string containing html text to be displayed in a JavaScript function?

```
String test = "DisplayNext(\"String containing html tags\")";

String NextLink = "<br><a href='#' onclick="+test+"> Next</a>";
```

JavaScript function:

```
function DisplayNext(Next){
    alert(Next);
}
```

I want to pass html tags to a JavaScript function and display it using an alert box..How do I do that ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to encode your html tags.

`>` becomes `&gt;`
`<` becomes `&lt;`
`"` becomes `&quot;`

You'll also need to encode your JavaScript.

`'` becomes `\'`

Then use single quotes to quote your JavaScript (so the double quotes don't close the onclick attribute prematurely):

```
String test = "DisplayNext('" + encodedHTML + "')";
String nextLink = "<br /><a href="#" onclick=\"" + test + "\"> Next</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript alert boxes aren't HTML viewers.  You can try replacing your alert calls with this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/messagebox